# BIOS flash XP, 1 long beep, 2 short beeps, over&over

Tags: bios

BIOS issue on HP dv9233cl laptop, wiped drive of Vista, loaded XP, not all the drives loaded. Went to the HP website, downloaded all drivers for this laptop. Started loading them. Loaded WIN Flash HP Network System BIOS Window SP42187. After a minute a low resolution screen appeared stating "It is now safe to turn off the computer" I waited a minute and half. Turned it off. Let it set 10 seconds try to start and No screen images at all and a nasty loud long beep 2 short beeps, 2 seconds of silence and it happens over & over again. I have unplugged/removed battery, still same problem,  Any sugg.... Thx.. Paul

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're getting a beep code which means the motherboard is having problems with some part of the system before it boots into an operating system. Unfortunately I looked around HP's website and i can't seem to find what 1 long, 2 short means for your system.

My suggestion is to check your manual for an explanation of what it means. It should be under troubleshooting if they offer any explanation. If it doesn't have an answer then you should call HP. They should know what the beep codes are for their own systems and will be able to tell you what's wrong with your system.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know @ hp, but the dell dimension gives the same beep code. I removed the memory and place one in dimm 1 and the second in dimm 3 and the computer booted properly.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that beep code indicates a memory issue. It could be as simple as re-seating (removing and replacing in the memory slots) or it could be as complicated as the memory controller on the motherboard. If the system is out of warranty, I would try re-seating first, and if that does not work, you can try running the HP on-board diagnostics by pressing F2 i believe on HP's.
If your computer is still under warranty, I would contact HP before you do anything. Simply removing the case incorrectly and causing damage that way can void the warranty. Hope that helps.